# Why is the number of orders of $6$ sandwiches using $3$ types of sandwiches a combinations with repetitions problem?

Tags: combinatorics

There are $3$ types of sandwiches, namely chicken (C), fish (F) and ham (H), available in a restaurant. A boy wishes to place an order of $6$ sandwiches. Assuming that there is no limit in the supply of sandwiches of each type, how many such orders can the boy place?

My Attempt:

I know that this is a stars and bars problem and the solution is $8 \choose 2$. But why can't it simply be $3^6$ where each of the $6$ sandwich places has $3$ choices to fill as repetition is allowed. I know I am missing something trivial.

Comment: Because order is not relevant.  $5$ chicken followed by one ham is the same as one ham followed by $5$ chicken.

Comment: So we use this just because order is not relevant, right??

Comment: yes.  $3^6$ would be the correct answer if we were keeping track of the order of the sandwiches.

Comment: Okay thank-you.

Comment: In this case, we need to ask whether order matters.  Does ordering chicken, fish, then ham in that order produce a different outcome than ordering fish, chicken, then ham in that order.  Since it does not, we are looking at a combinations with repetition problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us take Chicken and Ham sandwich and total order of 3. You are wondering why it should not be $2^3$ and why it is ${(3+2-1)\choose (2-1)}$

The $2^3=8$ choices that you mention are

- AAA - 3 Chicken sandwich
- AAB - 2 Chicken and 1 Ham
- ABA
- BAA
- ABB - 2 Ham and 1 Chicken
- BAB
- BBA
- BBB - 3 Ham

The total is $2^3$ but the chocies are merely ${(3+2-1)\choose (2-1)}$ = ${4\choose1}=4$

Comment: You are welcome!!